# How to update my data table with POST values. ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to update values ​​in my database. to make sure my script was working and to send the values ​​I created a POST method to check and the values ​​are coming.

[image: img]

My question now is with the values ​​coming to the method, how to update or save my values ​​in the database?

[image: img2]

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult EditPost(Programa_Cor_Info_Status statusData)
    {
        Programa_Cor_Info_Status status = new Programa_Cor_Info_Status
        {
            ID_Info = statusData.ID_Info,
            Status = statusData.Status,
            Obs = statusData.Obs,
        };

        return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I tried using db.savechanges on my controller but to no avail.
Could someone help me with an example?

Thanks

------------Update-----------------------------------------

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPost(Programa_Cor_Info_Status statusData, int ID_Status)
    {
        Programa_Cor_Info_Status status = new Programa_Cor_Info_Status
        {
            ID_Info = statusData.ID_Info,
            Status = statusData.Status,
            Obs = statusData.Obs,
        };

        var q = db.Programa_Cor_Info_Status.Where(m => m.ID_Info == ID_Status).FirstOrDefault();
        q.ID_Info = ID_Status;
        db.Entry(q).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[image: img3]

```
namespace Balu0._1.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Programa_Cor_Info_Status
 {
    public int ID_Info { get; set; }
    public int ID_Programa { get; set; }
    public int ID_Linha_Cor { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Obs { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have EF Core dbcontext in your project?

Comment: yes @Sergey i have

Comment: @mason I already updated my post with the error despite the only information I have is from the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help i already got !!!

```
db.Entry(status).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stll don't have, in your view add hidden model field with ID_Info value.
Change your action to this:

```
    public ActionResult EditPost(Programa_Cor_Info_Status statusData)
    {
            var existItem = db.Programa_Cor_Info_Status.Find(statusData.ID_Info);

// or if you dont have a  proper primary key you can try
 var existItem = db.Programa_Cor_Info_Status
                .Where( i=> i.ID_Info== statusData.ID_Info).FirstOrDefault();

                if (existItem != null)
                {
                    
                db.Entry(existItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(statusData);
                var result = db.SaveChanges(); // if result==0 then error
               } else ...error

        return Json(statusData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
Parameter name: keyValues'  - in this case it should be just one right?

Comment: Do you have complicated key of several properties? Pls show your Programa_Cor_Info_Status class.

Comment: i try to change for: var existItem = db.Programa_Cor_Info_Status.Where(s => s.ID_Info == statusData.ID_Info);

Comment: I don't see key attribute. What is the key for this class? This is why Find is not workign properly. Yes then you can use Where instead in this case.

Comment: the key is ID_Info